# Launching a URL in a Java Swing application

Tags: java

How do I launch a URL in the user's default browser, in code from a Java Swing application?

There is [this](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/netbeans/how-to-launch-a-web-browser-with-a-specified-url-from-an-a.html) Netbeans library, but the jar dont seem to contain the classes mentioned in the example.

And there seems to be a number of old bespoke [examples](http://www.centerkey.com/java/browser/) around.

But are there any killer solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're running on JDK 1.6, you [java.awt.Desktop](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html).

**Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new java.net.URI("www.google.com"));**

If running on an earlier JDK, I believe that you can download the [JDIC library](https://jdic.dev.java.net/). Or hack something together by spawning processes.

Answer (score 2):

To expand upon [kdgregory's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081159/launching-a-url-in-a-java-swing-application/2081187#2081187), the [The Java Desktop API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html), available from Java 6, provides integration with the desktop with functionality such as launching default web browsers and mail clients.

Launching a web browser can be achieved by using the [`Desktop.browse`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse(java.net.URI)) method.

For example, launching http://stackoverflow.com can be acheived by the following:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://stackoverflow.com"));
```

More information:

- [Using the Desktop API in Java SE 6](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/desktop_api/)
- [How to Integrate with the Desktop Class](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [BrowserLauncher](http://browserlaunch2.sourceforge.net/), although the latest version of the JDK are trying to make that obsolete.